# Calculate the following Limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan n^2\right)\cdot \ln n!$$

Tried l'Hopital but I think there is a better way that I'm not seeing it !

Comment: Another homework?

Comment: No, but I'm preparing for my first calculus exam on 23 January!

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: show that the searched limit is zero

Comment: 0*∞ is indetermination

Comment: pi/2-arctan(n^2)=arctan(1/n^2)  ?!! Am I right ?

Comment: That is correct, @Comrade57

Comment: Are you asking or affirming ? @ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log n! \leq n \log n$ while $\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan(n^2)=\arctan\frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{1}{n^2}$, hence the limit is zero.